# How can I rebase this git branch on master?

Tags: git, git-rebase

I have a git branch `axel` that I want to rebase on `master` using `git rebase master`.

But when I'm doing that, the result is like I had typed `git reset master --hard`.

What is happening here? How can I rebase my branch upon `master`?

Here's a visual representation depicting my git log:

[image: git log]

### EDIT

(followup)

[image: git log]

```
PS D:\Documents\…> git cat-file 48d0 -p
tree 2c70dc8ec913213a8b371e72ec7d0260f32fe60b
parent 0069be8975d4dd3c01afb6356eaf5c05019e2db0
parent 01724c632d34037ffcdc873e60f8224b80e281f1
author Axel … 1665479799 +0200
committer Axel … 1665479799 +0200
...
```

Comment: Perhaps the patch set is already included in master? But rebase should write a message when this is happening. Can you try `git rebase -i master`? And also [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551) – `git log` outputs text, so it can perfectly be included in a code block.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me. Regarding the image: I know. But you would have seen pretty much less in b/w than this colored output then.

Comment: `git rebase -i master` says: "noop". — and `# Rebase e8db69b..48d0443 onto e8db69b (1 command)`

Comment: What's the patch of commit 48d0443? Is it non-empty? Is it applied through a different commit on master already?

Comment: You need to reset hard back to `48d0443` first and then repeat the rebase if you want to see it again or use `-i` this time. Surely @knittl is right that commit `48d0443` is already fully covered by the new commits on `master`, so it "fell out" of the rebase because there were no changes left to make.

Comment: OK, regardless of *why*. Let's just prove it: `git switch axel` then `git reset --hard 48d0443` then `git rebase master --empty=keep --keep-empty`. Now your commit will be there on top of master for sure. Take a look at it and see if it's empty. If it is, that's why it fell out of the rebase. (Admittedly, I had to just lookup the docs to confirm if both of the empty options are needed, one for commits that become empty, and the other for commits that already were empty, though the latter is the default.)

Comment: Thanks for your replies. I'll try the keep-empty option tomorrow, when I'm back in the office. But be assured, there's loads of different code in my branch. I can see folders disappearing when I checkout the `master` branch or after I rebased. But when I hard-reset my branch, my new folders (with content) re-appear.

Comment: The `# noop` instruction sheet indicates that `git rebase` dropped your commit, presumably because it was patch-ID-identical to one of the commits on the `master` side. The image is unreadable and the hash IDs are impossible to copy-paste (because they're not text) but we can see that there's just one commit on `axel` (48d0443, if I didn't typo it) that's not on the target. I suspect that this one commit was cherry-picked into `master`, then reverted in `master`, which is what gets it dropped during rebase. In this case you'd want `--reapply-cherry-picks`.

Comment: Alternatively, it could be a fork-point issue, but that seems much less likely. If it *is* a fork-point issue, `--no-fork-point` would be required.

Comment: Or if the commit really was reverted, then `git rebase -f --onto master 01724c6 axel`

Comment: My common commit approach is to `git commit --amend --no-edit --reset-author` and `git push --force-with-lease`. So I won't have a long history of unfinished work. I'd expect `git gc` to drop all orphaned objects then after a while. … That's why I'm only having a single, yet large commit in the history.

Comment: Today, I made another strange observation: I never merged my branch. I only rebased onto `master` once some time ago. Now, I see a strange graph emitting from `0069be8`. I don't know what this red line is telling me. Does the new screenshot I just added to my question perhaps shed some light onto this issue?

Comment: Have you checked what the `diff` says, and then cross checked that the master branch didn't have them 'at some time', even if they've been effectively reverted (e.g. some one made a mistake and reset leaving an apparent revert commit)?

Comment: Looks like the only commit on `axel` that is not also in `master` *is* `axel` itself, and that is a merge commit. `git rebase` omits merge commits, therefore, the net result of your rebase operation is like a hard reset.

Comment: Yes, the missing piece of information (that you kept from us, perhaps because Git didn't make it clear to you either though) is that the commit you wanted to rebase is a merge commit, and rebase by default omits merge commits. You can use `--rebase-merges` to *re-perform* merges but that won't be what you want for this situation since you *amended* the merge.

Comment: Do you necessarily need to rebase? Simpl merge `axel` into master and be done (you can recreate `axel` from master then). Learn from not amending merge-commits and avoid it in the future.

Comment: I see. Yet, shouldn't `git` rather learn how to deal with such situation gracefully? The state of a branch's final commit should be nonrelevant when applying `rebase` (or `merge`). People, when getting in such situation by using automation scripts/tools, should be provided with a path forward by the `git` process itself, not by investigating and eventually finding themselves in a situation like this.

Answer (score 1):

As you can see, commit `48d0` is the only commit on branch `axel` that is not also in branch `master`. This commit is a merge commit.

When you run
`git rebase master`,
merge commits are omitted, therefore, no commits to be rebased remain, and the net result is the same as a `git reset --hard master`.

---

EDIT: It looks like there are additional edits in the merge commit (it's an "evil merge"). I would do this to make a new commit on top of `master`:

```
git checkout master
git merge --no-commit axel
# resolve conflicts if necessary
git reset   # forgets that there was a merge being made; keeps contents
git commit -a
```

This transfers the additional edits that the merge commit contains and puts them as new commit on the destination branch. But it does not keep the author and author date. If that is also important, use this and edit the commit message if necessary:

```
git commit -a -c axel
```

Comment: Ah, I see. Yet, when I run `git rebase master --rebase-merges`, the result is the same: It's like doing a hard reset to `master`. What should I do to get the desired effect of having the changes in `axel` applied on top of the current `master` branch?

Comment: In the situation presented, rebasing `axel` as a commit does not make sense. In fact, the content of this merge commit should be identical to `1f7756c` a.k.a `4.0.0`, because that one has the same parents. And since `4.0.0` is also an ancestor of `master`, it is totally correct that you get no new commit in the rebase operation.

Comment: So, the only solution to this situation seems to (1) copy the working directory somewhere, (2) forsake the `axel` branch, (3) checkout the `master` branch and (4) manually merge the contents from the copied working directory into the new `HEAD` using 3rd party diff-tools, then (5) commit as usual, am I right? — Would it make sense for `git` to emit an error when `amend`ing a merge commit?